# change background color of subplot area

Tags: matlab, figure, subplot

I have open a figure with 2 subplots ([1,2]). On the first subplot I am draw a point cloud object with size that is smaller then the subplot, like this (ignore the plot in subplot 2):
[image: my sitoation]
Note that the background of the figure has filled the space that isn't being used by subplot 1.

I am looking for a way to control the background color of space that isn't being used by subplot. For example, for red background:
[image: The desired situation]

Any ideas?

Comment: what about adding `set(H,'Color',[1 0 0]);` after drawing your plot? Here `H` is the handle to the 1st subplot

Comment: hi, thanks, but when I do that I get that only the white area in point cloud object 1 is turned to red and not all background color as I wanted

Comment: oh I see sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want easily. Probably the easiest thing to do is to place your plot within a [`uipanel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html) and set it that way

```
f = figure()
panel1 = uipanel('Parent', f, ...
                 'Units', 'norm', ...
                 'Position', [0 0 0.5 1], ...
                 'BorderType', 'none');

panel2 = uipanel('Parent', f, ...
                 'Units', 'norm', ...
                 'Position', [0.5 0 0.5 1], ...
                 'BorderType', 'none');

ax1 = axes('Parent', panel1);
ax2 = axes('Parent', panel2);

set(panel1, 'BackgroundColor', 'r')
set(panel2, 'BackgroundColor', 'g')
```

[image]

Comment: hi, after doing what you said, I got this error: <No appropriate method, property, or field 'Renderer' for class 'matlab.ui.container.Panel'.

Error in showPointCloud (line 119)
if strcmpi(hFigure.Renderer, 'painters')

Error in LiDAR_fussion (line 12)
    hAxes = showPointCloud(ptCloudScene,'Parent',h, 'VerticalAxis','Y', 'VerticalAxisDir',
    'Down');

Error in control_panel (line 258)
        [ptCloudScene,fixed,moving,accumTform,xyz_array,hAxes,h_calc] = ...> do you know how to solve it? (sorry for how the post looks, I dont know how to fix it)

Comment: What is `h` that you are passing to `showPointCloud`?

Comment: hi. thanks a lot for the help! my code has changed since the last post, and now I cant understand how I got this error. However, when I am writhing: 'ptCloudScene = pcread('teapot.ply');
hAxes = showPointCloud(ptCloudScene,'VerticalAxis','Z', 'VerticalAxisDir', 'Down');
cameratoolbar('SetCoordSys','z') 
panel1 = uipanel('Parent',f);
set(hAxes,'parent',panel1)'   I get the point cloud inside the uipanel, but it is small and isnt located at the center

Comment: Maybe change `set(hAxes, 'Parent', panel1)` to be `set(hAxes, 'Parent', panel1, 'Units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.05 0.05 0.9 0.9])`

Comment: hi, it didn't solve the problem 8-( I am going to post anter quastion about is, with my code

Comment: here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743996/control-point-cloud-view-in-figure-in-code

Comment: @TomE8 It's best to not start a new question and simply figure out what's going wrong here. Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?